# Python discord.py pulling jokes from https://some-random-api.ml/joke

Tags: python, api, discord.py

I am trying to use some random API to get jokes for my discord bot.  This is my code

```
import discord
import random
import aiohttp
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

    @client.command()
    async def joke(ctx):
       async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
          # This time we'll get the joke request as well!
          request = await session.get('https://some-random-api.ml/joke')
          jokejson = await request.json()
    
       embed = discord.Embed(title="I know its funny", color=discord.Color.purple())
       embed.set_footer(text=jokejson['Joke'])
       await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

It runs but when I use .joke I get the error `discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'Joke'`  I was hoping someone could tell me where I when wrong.

Comment: That would imply that `jokejson` does not have a key `Joke`. What are the contents of `jokejson`when you attempt to access it? Should that be inside the with block?

Comment: @HenryEcker I seemed to have fixed it by adding an extra space.  I do not know why it worked but I added an extra line when trying to check the contest of jokejson so thank you.

Comment: In your solution `'joke'` is lowercase. In the question `'Joke'` has a capital `J`. It was not the space. You changed the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed joke in `embed.set_footer(text=jokejson['Joke'])` in set it to `embed.set_footer(text=jokejson['joke'])` so that jokes is the same as in the json

```
@client.command()
async def joke(ctx):
   async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
      # This time we'll get the joke request as well!
      request = await session.get('https://some-random-api.ml/joke')
      jokejson = await request.json()

   
   embed = discord.Embed(title="I know its funny", color=discord.Color.purple())
   embed.set_footer(text=jokejson['joke'])
   await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

This works

Comment: Can you please explain your answer so that anyone who sees this gets to know why this is done.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @MΛIK I will do that now. Sorry I am still learning the best way of using StackOverflow as I am a new user

Comment: @Michael We've all started, don't worry! Your answer is not bad, you just could provide some additional informations to make it slightly better!